# Can´t retrieve a Web Service Response using C# or VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, soap

I have to create an app that sends some data to a (SOAP)WebService and show its response. It seems simple but the problem is that after consuming the WS, the variable remains empty. I tried both C# and VB with no luck.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CardifWS.RequestContactWsService webService = new CardifWS.RequestContactWsService();

            string usuario = "user987";
            string name = "teste2003 1552";
            string cpf = "123456789";
            string email = "email@gmail.com";
            string zipCode = "04536010";
            string city = "sao paulo";
            string neighborhood = "itaim";
            string state = "sp";
            string address = "itaim";
            string addressNumber = "98";
            string addressComp = "2";
            int dddPhone = 11;
            string phone = "12345678";
            int dddCellPhone = 11;
            string cellPhone = "1187654321";
            int fipeCode = 123456;
            string chassi = "123456789";  
            string renavam = "987654321";
            string placa = "abc3456";
            string marca = "ford";
            string modelo = "ka";
            int colorCode = 456;
            int anoFabricacao = 2010;
            int anoModelo = 2011;
            int indice = 1;
            string[] parametros = "7".Split(' ');
            string bestTimeCall = "T";

            CardifWS.RequestContactResponse respuesta = webService.requestContact(usuario, name, cpf, email, zipCode, city,
                                                                                neighborhood, state, address, addressNumber,
                                                                                addressComp, dddPhone, phone, dddCellPhone,
                                                                                cellPhone, fipeCode, chassi, renavam, placa,
                                                                                marca, modelo, colorCode, anoFabricacao,
                                                                                anoModelo, indice, parametros, bestTimeCall);

            Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", respuesta.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("errorCode: {0}", respuesta.errorCode.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("errorDesc: {0}", respuesta.errorDesc);
            Console.WriteLine("id: {0}", respuesta.id.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the WS URL

http://directsales2.uat.cardif.com.br:8080/autofacil-ws/services/RequestContactWs?wsdl

Using WireShark I know for sure that the WS is sending me the response, but some reason .NET seems to not be able to read it.

I´m using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: what do you mean by 'the variable remains empty'? what properties does the `CardifWS.ReuqestContactResponse` class have? are those empty?

Comment: it has three properties, errorCode, errorDesc and id. all of them remain as null.

Comment: Look closely at the XML namespaces. Any time I hear "received XML response and it's null" (or "deserialized XML response and it's null"), I think of namespace differences.

Comment: Is it possible you could include in your post a sample response XML from wireshark, and the implementation of `CardifWS.RequestContactResponse` class?  It should be possible to deserialize directly or determine the problem from that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, once I knew it was a namespace issue I just modified the response namespace in the Reference.cs file, inside the web references folder, and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the service and apparently the namespace for the response is different from the service namespace.

- Response : Namespace="http://response.autofacil.cardif.com.br
- Service : Namespace="http://webservice.autofacil.cardif.com.br

I used svcutil.exe to generate a proxy class for the webservice

```
SvcUtil.exe /o:c:\temp\foo.cs http://directsales2.uat.cardif.com.br:8080/autofacil-ws/services/RequestContactWs?wsdl
```

Import the class into your project, and add the service to the app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="RequestContactWsSoapBinding" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://directsales2.uat.cardif.com.br:8080/autofacil-ws/services/RequestContactWs"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RequestContactWsSoapBinding"
        contract="Cardif.Autofacil.WebService.RequestContactWs" name="RequestContactWs" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

After that you can change the namespace for the RequestContactResponse in the imported class

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace ="http://webservice.autofacil.cardif.com.br")]
public partial class RequestContactResponse
```